# How to use AND and VLOOKUP functions to assess multiple items without getting N/A or VALUE errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to check two things.

1. Whether the "Type" (A Column) is the value "Secondary".
2. Whether the "Topic" (value - B Column) can be found in the table on the right shown below.

[image]

As you can see in my formula below, there are multiple nested if statements. Each new nesting still checks to see if "Secondary" is present. However, each new one checks a different column in the right-side table.

What is occurring is that if the "Type" value is not "Secondary" then it shows "N/A". However, even if the value is "Secondary" and its topic is shown in the right side table, the output is "Value". These are correct, but it should output the appropriate value.

What am I doing wrong or what could I do to get this formula to function as I am explaining?

```
=IF(AND(A2="Secondary",VLOOKUP(B2,$G$3:$G$22,1,FALSE)),"Information",IF(AND(A2="Secondary",VLOOKUP(B2,$I$3:$J$22,1,TRUE)),"Floorplan","False"))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what the "appropriate value" would look like, what do you want to see in `C`?

Comment: @YisroelTech Cell C4 should output "Information" and cell C5 should output "Floorplan". Their respective true part of the conditions output.

Comment: And the other two cells, "False".

Comment: I think a `COUNTIF` is what you need instead of `VLOOKUP`. `VLOOKUP` is to bring back a value from the matched ranged, which you do not need

Comment: @YisroelTech Doesn't the COUNTIF function output a numeric count? I just want to do a lookup, verify if the value is there and then produce the value I set in the formula.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` doesn't output your needed value either, it outputs the B4 value. What I meant with `COUNTIF` was to do the 2nd part of your `AND` to be something like `COUNTIF($G$3:$G$22,B4)>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with the *#N/A* in `C5`, comes from the `=VLOOKUP(B5,$G$3:$G$22,1,FALSE)` (the 2nd part of the first `AND`) results in a #N/A throwing off the whole following function to stop working.

And the *#VALUE!* in `C4` is because your `AND` isn't on two logical things, as the output of the `VLOOKUP` is not a logic but a string.

---

I think you can use `COUNTIF` and check if it's greater than 0 - is found - for the 2nd of the `AND`).

Use this in `C2` and drag the fill handle down:
`=IF(AND(A2="Secondary",COUNTIF($G$3:$G$22,B2)>0),"Information",IF(AND(A2="Secondary",COUNTIF($I$3:$J$22,B2)>0),"Floorplan","False"))`

Comment: Ahhhh makes total sense now! Thank you, this new approach works perfect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(A2="Secondary",IFERROR(IF(EXACT(VLOOKUP(B2,$G$3:$G$22,1,FALSE),B2),"Information"),"N/A"),"N/A")
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.